# EJS Function is not calling the values from Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to show the values in a .ejs file from Express. But I am getting a blank output. If I use forEach function I am getting all the values. I don't want to create any loops. I just want fetch only the single values from Express.

```js
<% playerdetails= function(a){ %>
    <%= a.FirstName %>
<% } %>
```

Using forEach: This is working Fine

```js
  <% playerdetails.forEach(function(a){ %>
        <%= a.FirstName %>
    <% }) %>
```

Please find the below express code from app.js and it is fetching the data from Mongo DB.

```js
app.get("/",function(req,res){
    Players.find({},function(err,playerdetails){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            res.render("index",{playerdetails:playerdetails});
        }
    });
    
});
```

Alos please find the sample data from Mongo DB

```js
Players.create({
    FirstName : "Vidya",
    LastName  : "Malla",
    Image     : "sample.png",
    Mobile    : 6097892088,
    Gender    : "Male",
    DOB       : 1985-09-09,
    Comment   : "This is my first Post"
});
```

Actually, I am a new bee to the programming languages don't know where I am doing wrong.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: I'm confused. Are you trying to grab just one item from the array? Are you trying for all of them? Maybe just a few? Please be more clear for me.

Comment: It would help people to help you if you showed three things.  1) What exactly is the Javascript data you're starting with and how are you calling `res.render()` with that data?  We need to know precisely what the data is (arrays, objects, individual values, etc...), 2) What HTML are you trying to end up with after the render? and 3) What EJS templates have you tried and what result or error did they produce?

Comment: Apologize for not sharing the brief information. Now I have updated my original post.

Comment: @SunburntRock89 Yes I just want to grab only one item from Mongo DB and render it to the index.ejs file.